# Minimally non-alternating links

Tags: knot-theory

I call a non-alternating link "minimally-..." if it can be obtained by taking an alternating link and flipping a crossing. I guess at least all algebraic link have the property. Do you have a proof, a counterexample or even an extension to transcendent links? Note that the diagram doesn't need to have minimal number of crossings possible!
Random example: Flipping the "special" crossing of $7^3_1$ gives $6^3_3$. So this diagram of $6^3_3$ is m-n-a in my sense, but obviously has 7 crossings, one more than possible.
EDIT using the comment of Josh: So my main question, in established terms, is: Are all arborescent links almost-alternating? (My instinct says yes, and it would be most interesting for me if you come up with a counterexample.)
SON OF EDIT: Even more interesting from a practical standpoint is the following question. Cut all connections between two crossings where a link doesn't alternate. Does every arborescent link have a diagram where this cutting process gives only two tangles with 4 open ends? And both tangles are arborescent too? (The two questions are independent! If yes to Q1 and you cut out just the one "wrong" crossing, the remain is not necessary arborescent themself. Or am I wrong here?)

Comment: Such links are called almost alternating. You should also look at papers on the dealternating number and the alternation number. It is known that all non-alternating Montesinos links are almost alternating, but I do not know if this is known for all arborescent links.

Comment: What do *algebraic* and *transcendent* mean in this context, please?

Comment: @Gerry: "Arborescent" is the more common name for "algebraic", although I prefer the latter. "Transcendent" is the opposite of "algebraic", e.g. the knot 8-18.